# Tds adapter supports only on_conflict: :raise (insert using on_conflict option)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Im on phoenix tutorial but using the Tds adapter (SQL Server), at the shopping cart behavior. The code fails using the on_conflict option for insert, here is the code

```
def add_item_to_cart(%Cart{} = cart, %Catalog.Product{} = product) do
    %CartItem{quantity: 1, price_when_carted: product.price}
    |> CartItem.changeset(%{})
    |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:cart, cart)
    |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:product, product)
    |> Repo.insert(
      on_conflict: [inc: [quantity: 1]],
      conflict_target: [:cart_id, :product_id]
    )
  end
```

The error is Tds adapter supports only `on_conflict: :raise`
I'm trying to follow the tutorial and want to know if it is a dead-end or if there is an alternative to achieve the same.

Comment: you should check whether MSSQL supports updates on conflicts, because even for postgres it is a relatively new feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three alternatives.

- use what the host DB supports (`on_conflict: :raise`), `rescue` the raised exception, and execute another query that would increase `quantity` by `1` from `rescue` clause
- start with issuing `select` query for `[:cart_id, :product_id]` and if it returned an empty result, call `add_item_to_cart/2`, otherwise increase `quantity` by `1`
- [**the best one**] use the database that is recommended for this tutorial (e. g. *PostgreSQL*)